# hide play button after it has been show in slide show

Tags: slideshow

I am making a slide show. Trying to hide play button when it is visible if user does not click on button.

```
function hidePlay (){

    if($("#playAuto").is(":visible") == true ) {

            $('body').not('#playAuto').on('click', function(){
            $('#playAuto').fadeOut(2000);
            });
        }

    else {

           $('#slideshow').on('click', function() {
                $('#playAuto, #largeImg, #actionsCon').fadeIn(5000);
                alert('finding #playAuto');
           });

         } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to hide the button if the user does not click it for an amount of time. Otherwise the page starts, at this moment the user does not click the button and it will be hidden. At this time the user is not able to click the button so it will be hidden forever. You can set a variable if the user clicks the button. Hide the button delayed (setTimeout) and first check if the user clicked the button before hiding it.
Pseudo-code:

```
$('btn').click(function() {
  wasClicked = true;
}

setTimeout(function() {
  if(wasClicked == false) {
    $('btn').fadeOut(500);
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: The auto play button is shown when the user clicks on the image of the slide show. That is in the else statement. The DOM doe not seem to recognize the if statement, in other words it does not realize when the play button is visible.